# How to solve the .Net framework version compatibility error with .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

This question may be asked before but I did not got the issue solved visiting many questions on Stackoverflow.

I am creating a test project for my for my console app project.When I add referance of console app  to the test project it shows me following error:

```
`Project '..\MyConsoleApp.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2`'
```

I tried by lowering the version of .NETFramework for my test project but then it showed to reinstall the Nuget pakages. When I tried to reinstall them it shows that *the pakage has a bug, contact the owner*.

Open for suggestions from u guys...Thanks

Comment: The message is clear that your test project (.NET Framework) cannot add a .NET Core project as reference. Create a .NET Core based test project please.

Comment: What .NET framework version(s) did you try to set it to?  I've had similar problems recently, trying to resolve an upgrade to 4.7.2.  I had to roll back to 4.7.  I think there's a glitch(?) in NUGET, it doesn't seem to care if the package it gets will create bad library references under your selected version.

Comment: @Phill I tried out 4.5, 4.6, 4.5.1 versions but he issue remained same.

Answer (score 0):

Target netstandard instead of core or framework.

Answer (score 0):

Lex Li's comment was very helpful in my case I was wrong in adding general test project instead I added .Net Core test project which solved the problem like this:
[image: In my case it was a XUnit Test Project (.NET Core)]

Hope my answer will be helpful for beginners like me....